# Google Analytics - Event Tracking not reported

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking

We've implemented Event Tracking code that runs for a while now (more than a week), but we don't see any events in the Events reporting page.
I've tested with Google Analytics Debugger chrome extension, which recognizes the event and claims it's error-less. This means the event is sent to google.

Additional info that might help - we're using virtual page when calling to `_trackPageview` (and this is the only call to `_trackPageview` we have).

Initialization example: `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/v/user/store/catalog'])`

An example of an event: `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','LinkToProduct','CatalogProductbox','3',0,false])`

What can I do to debug this further or solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Double check that the correct Account ID is on the _trackEvent call via the Google Analytics Debugger. The Account ID is passed via the utmac parameter.
2. Are there any filters on the Analytics Profile that might be keeping event data from being recorded?
3. Are you seeing pageviews for your virtual page `/v/user/store/catalog`?

Comment: 1. Double checked.
3. Yes.
2. It turns out we had a filter for pages starting with '/v/', which may have filtered the events which are reported using the original page path, that doesn't contain '/v/'. I'll check in a few hours to see if it's updated, and then accept as an answer :-)

Comment: So it was the filtering! Important to notice that it's not possible to change your event page, even if you're using virtual pages. Many thanks!